# could not upload ios app to AppStore showing this error

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

could not upload ios app to AppStore showing this error
[image]

Comment: Change the network and try again.

Comment: changed to 4g (70 Mbs) not fix

Comment: Try to connect to apple developer and connect to your account to see if it is a networks problem or apple connection problem .